# add icons to JTree

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtree, renderer

How can I add icons to a JTree. I want add a different icon to a root and different icons to the leafs of the root and different to the leafs of a leaf.

I am implementing a Jtree to show a user, the albums of the user and the photos in the inside a particular album. So three different types of icons..

Comment: is there a step by step tutorial which I can follow don't know anything about JTrees..

Comment: See [*How to Use Trees*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html); the example's model is the default for `new Jtree()`.